# Django Render HTML via AJAX - Missing Context Variable Data

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-templates

In my Django web app, I'm trying to dynamically update only a certain section of my page via AJAX, but doing so by returning/replacing HTML in a child template (`{% include 'keywords.html' %}`). I understand that I can (and maybe should) return a JsonResponse (and I have done so successfully), but I'd like to try and get the below implementation working (as others seem to have).

The view successfully returns the HTML to the AJAX response, but lacking the data contained in  the `keywords` context variable.

**templates/index.html**

```
...
<div id="keywords">
    {% include 'keywords.html' %}
</div>
...
```

**templates/keywords.html**

```
<div id="keywords">
{% if keywords %}
  {% for keyword in keywords %}
    <p>{{keyword.word}}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
def add_keyword(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = KeywordForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

            ...

            keywords = Keywords.objects.values()...

            print(keywords) # this works, contains a queryset with data

            context = {
                keywords: keywords,
            }

            # i've also tried return HttpResponse(render_to_string(...)) 
            # with same result
            return render(request, 'keywords.html', context))
```

**index.js**

```
// i've also tried jquery .load()
$.ajax({
        url: data.url,
        type: "POST",
        data:
        {
          keyword: keyword,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: data.csrf_token
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $("#keywords").html(data);
        }
      });
```

**AJAX Response data:**

```
<div id="keywords">

</div>
```

What might I be missing, or doing wrong?

Comment: in your context you are missing quotes, when returning the page you have one extra parentheses and place your templates like templates/app_name/keywords.html check these then we will figure out where we are lacking. It works on my system.

Comment: It was the missing quotes - bah! Thanks for the extra set of eyes. The extra parentheses was just a copy and paste error into the question. If you submit this as an answer, then I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context you are missing quotes, when returning the page you have one extra parentheses. It works on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You can render your template with context data using the **loade** and **context** 
it will do first templates using jinja context will render in html then return final html text then you can pass using **JsonResponse**

try following stuff then let me know

@view.py

```
from django.template import context,loader
...

def render_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = KeywordForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            keywords = Keywords.objects.values()
            print(keywords) # this works, contains a queryse
            context = {
                keywords: keywords,
            } 
            template = loader.get_template('keywords.html')
            html = template.render(context)
            print(html)
            return JsonResponse({'html':html},status=200,content_type="application/json")
```

@in ajax call success method you should render

```
 success: function(data) {
          $("#keywords").html(data);
          //or
          //ordocument.getElementById('keywords').innerHTML=data;
        }
```

if works or not let me know?